# How to save 'Yes' or 'No' instead of 'true' or 'false' with Rails check_box form helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, checkbox, rails-activerecord

I have an object `@recipient` with attribute `responding`. Say, I want `responding` to store "Yes" or "No" via `=f.check_box :responding, {}, 'Yes', 'No'`, which [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box) indicate is possible.

The form submits `Yes` or `No` and PostgreSQL UPDATE statement uses `Yes` or `No` as expected (I see that in `$ rails server` terminal window). But - regardless of the `responding` attribute's data type (boolean or string) - what ends up stored in the db is always `true` or `false`. I'm perplexed. What's going on behind the scenes? How can I force Rails to store `Yes` or `No`? Should I (not)? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: What data type is the 'responding' field in your d/b schema?

Comment: The `responding` attribute is a string field in the db.

Comment: Are you sure it is a string? What does the table's schema look like?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure of that; schema reads: `t.string "responding", limit: 255`.

Comment: @muistooshort, although the issue was not having restarted the server after migrating, I wish I had more time to read your answer; the general points you made in it were very helpful. If you decide to repost, that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, I just undeleted it.

Answer (score 3):

From the [fine manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-boolean.html):

> **8.6. Boolean Type**
>   [...]
>   Valid literal values for the "true" state are:
>
> ```
> TRUE
> 't'
> 'true'
> 'y'
> 'yes'
> 'on'
> '1'
> ```
>
> For the "false" state, the following values can be used:
>
> ```
> FALSE
> 'f'
> 'false'
> 'n'
> 'no'
> 'off'
> '0'
> ```

So the strings `'yes'` and `'no'` are valid aliases for `true` and `false` (respectively) in SQL.

If you set a boolean column to `'yes'` then you'll get `true` back when you access the value in Rails. `'yes'` is an alias for `TRUE` in SQL and Rails represents the `TRUE` SQL boolean value with Ruby's `true`. Similarly for `'no'` and `false`.

You're better off translating the `true` and `false` Ruby values to `'Yes'` and `'No'` when you display your model rather than worrying about the specific representation of your booleans inside the database.

---

Not sure if this really applies as there has been some confusion about server restarts and what the column type really is. The OP wanted another read so I undeleted this.

Answer (score 1):

So, if you use

```
=f.check_box :responding, {}, 'Yes', 'No'
```

with the normal `form_for @recipient` it should present you one check box which has the value yes. if the check_box is checked the value saved is 'Yes'. Using :string for column. If unchecked value is 'no'. 
This would be normal procedure. Well, all I can see is that you use checkbox instead of check_box.

It should be datatype :string. Are you sure you are using :string and not boolean? If you use boolean it will save true. Did you properly migrate after a change and did you check the *schema.rb*...
However, I am just trying to help, but if this does not work for you I have no idea what the problem might be.
Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: I properly migrated; back and forth couple times to see how it behaves for boolean. `checkbox` is a typo here, I'll correct it. The issue resolved itself after I restarted the server (surprisingly, normally I don't restart server after migrating). It behaves as expected now. Thank you.

Comment: You should always restart the server after running a migration.